# Does someone know to fix this error? I don't know its for a note on school

Tags: python-3.x, replit

For school I need to write a code that will play Hangman with you but, there is a error which I can't fix. The error is in the part of the print, I think it has something to do with the import but I am not sure (the error is a invalid syntax)

I tried to put the print and the message on different lines but I didn't work, I also tried a colon behind the print but also that didn't solve the problem (I am in Python 3.6.1 on repl.it)

https://repl.it/@Informatica132/Galgje

It has to print: "Your right" Character "is in the chosen word", or "Your wrong" Character "is not in the chosen word" but it prints a syntaxerror invalid syntax.

Comment: Little heads up: you're, not your

Comment: Sorry, my english isn't so good, I had to translate the code from dutch to English so there can be some grammer errors

Comment: perfectly understandable

Answer (score 0):

Errors, errors everywhere. I have fixed all the syntax errors, but you still need to figure out your program logic. (Currently it lets you guess a single letter before exiting.)

```
import random
Trys = 0
Words = ["Hey" , "Hello" , "mate" , "victory" , "wineglass" , "UK"]
Word =  (random.choice(Words))
Character = str(input("type one character to look if it is in the chosen word"))
if Character in Word:
  print ("Your right", Character, "is in the chosen word")
  Trys = Trys + 1
else:
  print ("Your wrong", Character, "is not in the chosen word")
  Trys = Trys + 1
```

Comment: I know it exits after guessing 1 letter, I still need to add a loop, but first I want to fix the erros so later on they are fixed